# what is the supposed size of address bus 16 bits to address a memory of 8ko?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I don't know how to distinguish between the size of bus address and memory size when I supposed to answer this question in my homework:
what is the supposed size of address bus 16 bits to address a memory of 8kilobytes = 8192 bytes ?

Comment: What's "8ko"? Is that supposed to be 8KiB (8 KibiBytes, as in 8192 8-bit Bytes)?

Comment: @Spiff yes 8ko is equal to 8192 bits

Comment: Your question has several unstated assumptions.  What unit does *"memory size"* represent?  What is the unit of addressability?  Modern microprocessors assume memory  units of byte, but historically memory has also been addressable in other sizes units, e.g.  16-bit words.

Comment: I am working for now on 16-bit words @sawdust

Comment: 8ko is 8 “kilo octets”, where an [octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)) is an 8-bit byte. I’ve seen it predominantly being used in the French language, but I have also seen it used in other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 8Kbytes (8192 bytes), you need *13* bits to address.

13 bits let you create addresses from 0000000000000 binary (0 decimal) to 1111111111111 binary (8191 decimal).

If you meant decimal 8000, you'll still need 13 bits.

If the register or space to hold this quantity is 16 bits, it's fine, you just won't use the "most significant 3" bits and those would stay 0.

```
4  2 1
0  0 0 5 2  1
9  4 2 1 5  2 6 3 1
6  8 4 2 6  8 4 2 6  8 4 2 1

+--+-+-+-+--+-+-+-+--+-+-+-+

1  1 1 1 
3  2 1 0 9  8 7 6 5  4 3 2 1
```

Comment: @AkramBENGHANEM *"8ko is equal to 8192 bits"*  -- This answer does not correlate with your previous comment.

Comment: @AkramBENGHANEM I'm glad you accepted but honestly I didn't understand your question very well.  You should update it and explain how it helped you so others can benefit from the answer better.

Comment: @sawdust, AkramBenghanem was wrong: 8ko = 8Kx8 bits = 8KB.